# Компьютерная геометрия - трансформация квадрата в одну прямую

Tags: javascript, svg, геометрия, svg-animation, maple

Есть задача дан квадрат ABCD в точке A разрыв с помощью различных преобразований , сделать из него прямую ABCDA* желательно по оси OX . 
Не прошу решить задачу(но если возможно будет отлично) прошу помочь в нахождении материала. Книги , что то еще. Или форумы . Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: как двигать точку по по окружности знаете?

Comment: Примерно понимаю.

Comment: Вот поочередно двигайте точки по по окружности на 90 градусов вокруг точки, которая является предыдущей сначала точку A вокруг D, потом A и D вокруг С, потом A,D,C вокруг B

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/QF86v0N.png

Comment: мне весь квадрат надо развернуть , по такому методу получиться?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Решение SVG

Как комментировал @Stranger in the Q:

> Вот поочередно двигайте точки по  окружности на 90 градусов вокруг
>   точки, которая является предыдущей, сначала точку A вокруг D, потом A и
>   D вокруг С, потом A,D,C вокруг B

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для реализации этого алгоритма создадим четыре прямых линии и будем поочередно поворачивать каждую из них на 90 градусов вокруг точек, которые находятся на концах этих линий.

Чтобы сохранить конечное положение линии после завершения анимации применим `fill="freeze"`

Последовательность выполнения анимаций реализуется с помощью условия:

```
begin="an_AD.end+1s"
```

То есть вторая анимация вращения прямой `DC` начнется после завершения анимации вращения первой линии

Итак для всех последовательных анимаций вращения линий:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="500" height="800" viewBox="0 0 500 800" >  
   
 <circle cx="100" cy="250" fill="none" r="100" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="4 8" stroke-linecap="round" />
<rect x="100" y="250" width="100" height="100"   fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="2 4" stroke-linecap="round" /> 

  <polyline points="100,350 100,250" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" >

  <!-- Анимация поворота отрезка прямой AD вокруг точки D -->
    <animateTransform id="an_AD"
      attributeName="transform"
   type="rotate"
   begin="0s"
   dur="2s"
   values="
   0 100 250;
   90 100 250;"
   fill="freeze"/>
  </polyline>  
    <polyline points="100,250 200,250" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" > 

       <!-- Анимация поворота отрезка прямой DC вокруг точки C -->
      <animateTransform id="an_DC"
           attributeName="transform"
           type="rotate"
           begin="an_AD.end+1s"
           dur="2s"
           values="0 200 250;90 200 250;"
           fill="freeze"/> 
      </polyline>
 <polyline points="200,250 200,350" fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" > 
  
  <!-- Анимация поворота отрезка прямой CB вокруг точки B -->
        <animateTransform id="an_CB"
            attributeName="transform"
            type="rotate"
            begin="an_DC.end+1s"
            dur="2s"
            values="0 200 350;90 200 350;"
            fill="freeze"/>   
 </polyline> 
    <polyline points="200,350 100,350" fill="none" stroke="violet" stroke-width="2" > 
    
         <!-- Анимация поворота отрезка прямой BA вокруг точки A -->
        <animateTransform id="an_BA"
           attributeName="transform"
           type="rotate"
           begin="an_CB.end+1s"
           dur="2s"
           values="0 100 350;90 100 350;"
           fill="freeze"/>  
       </polyline>  
  
</svg>
```

Результат получился явно не тот, который требуется, но он наглядно показывает как работают трансформации в SVG.

Чтобы заставить при анимации поворота второй линии вращаться вместе с ней первую линию, нужно объединить их в группу `<g>...</g>` и вращать группу вокруг точки `C`

Итак проделаем со всеми линиями дополнительно вкладывая группу в группу:

```
<g id="gr_AD_DC_CB_BA">
    <g id="gr_AD_DC_CB">
     <g id="gr_AD_DC">
```

**Финальное расположение развернутой линии по вертикали**

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('svg1');
svg.addEventListener("click",() =>{
  an_AD.beginElement();
})
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="500" height="800" viewBox="0 0 500 800" >  
   
 <circle cx="100" cy="250" fill="none" r="100" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="4 8" stroke-linecap="round" />
<rect x="100" y="250" width="100" height="100"   fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="2 4" stroke-linecap="round" /> 
<g id="gr_AD_DC_CB_BA">
 <g id="gr_AD_DC_CB">
  <g id="gr_AD_DC">
  <polyline points="100,350 100,250" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" >

  <!-- Анимация поворота отрезка прямой AD вокруг точки D -->
    <animateTransform id="an_AD"
      attributeName="transform"
   type="rotate"
   begin="undefinite"
   dur="3s"
   values="
   0 100 250;
   90 100 250;"
   fill="freeze"/>
  </polyline>  
    <polyline points="100,250 200,250" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" /> 

       <!-- Анимация поворота отрезка прямой DC вокруг точки C -->
      <animateTransform id="an_DC"  attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="an_AD.end+1s" dur="3s" values="0 200 250;90 200 250;" fill="freeze"/> 
   </g>   
   <polyline points="200,250 200,350" fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" /> 
  
  <!-- Анимация поворота отрезка прямой CB вокруг точки B -->
        <animateTransform id="an_CB"  attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="an_DC.end+1s" dur="3s" values="0 200 350;90 200 350;" fill="freeze"/>   
 </g> 
    <polyline points="200,350 100,350" fill="none" stroke="violet" stroke-width="2" /> 
    
         <!-- Анимация поворота отрезка прямой BA вокруг точки A -->
        <animateTransform id="an_BA"  attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="an_CB.end+1s" dur="3s" values="0 100 350;90 100 350;" fill="freeze"/>  
</g> 
  <text x="60" y="200" font-size="24" fill="dodgerblue" >Click me</text>
  
</svg>
```

**Финальное расположение развернутой линии по горизонтали**

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('svg1');
svg.addEventListener("click",() =>{
  an_AD.beginElement();
})
```

```html
<!-- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1040793/28748 -->
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" >  
   
 <circle cx="100" cy="250" fill="none" r="100" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="4 8" stroke-linecap="round" />
<rect x="100" y="250" width="100" height="100"   fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="2 4" stroke-linecap="round" /> 

 <g id="gr_AD_DC_CB">
  <g id="gr_AD_DC">
  <polyline points="100,350 100,250" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" >

  <!-- Анимация поворота отрезка прямой AD вокруг точки D -->
    <animateTransform id="an_AD"
      attributeName="transform"
   type="rotate"
   begin="indefinite"
   dur="3s"
   values="
   0 100 250;
   90 100 250;"
   fill="freeze"/>
  </polyline>  
    <polyline points="100,250 200,250" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" /> 

       <!-- Анимация поворота отрезка прямой DC вокруг точки C -->
      <animateTransform id="an_DC"
           attributeName="transform"
           type="rotate"
           begin="an_AD.end+1s"
           dur="3s"
           values="0 200 250;90 200 250;"
           fill="freeze"/> 
   </g>   
   <polyline points="200,250 200,350" fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" /> 
  
  <!-- Анимация поворота отрезка прямой CB вокруг точки B -->
        <animateTransform id="an_CB"
           attributeName="transform"
           type="rotate"
           begin="an_DC.end+1s"
           dur="3s"
           values="0 200 350;90 200 350;"
           fill="freeze"/>   
 </g> 
    <polyline points="200,350 100,350" fill="none" stroke="violet" stroke-width="2" /> 
 <text x="60" y="200" font-size="24" fill="dodgerblue" >Click me</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Последний поворот - не нужен (+)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  согласен, сейчас подправлю.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно будет полезен)